# Muxing files with different run times

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, mp4, mkv

I've got a few files I want to mux.
File 1: MP4 File with runtime of 23 Minutes 45 Seconds
File 2: MP4 File with runtime of 23 Minutes 39 Seconds
File 3: Subtitle File
File 4: Subtitle File
File 5: Subtitle File
File 6: Subtitle File
File 7: Subtitle File
File 8: Subtitle File
File 9: Subtitle File

I'm trying to mux these files. Now, since there's a runtime difference, I'm getting weird errors like :

```
[matroska @ 0x55e029fbd1a0] Only audio, video, and subtitles are supported for Matroska.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of /root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [Dual Audio].mkv: Invalid argument
```

I can mux files with same run time just fine... but, I'm stuck on this one. Can someone help me out here.

The command I'm using :

```
ffmpeg -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [enUS].mp4" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [jaJP].mp4" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [enUS] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [itIT] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [esLA] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [frFR] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [esES] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [deDE] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [ruRU] .ass" -i "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [ptBR] .ass" -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 -map 5 -map 6 -map 7 -map 8  -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 title="English Audio" -metadata:s:a:1 title="Japanese Audio" -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=jpn -metadata:s:s:0 title="English (US) Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:1 title="Italian Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:2 title="Spanish (Latin America) Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:3 title="French Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:4 title="Spanish Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:5 title="Deutsch Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:6 title="Russian Subtitle" -metadata:s:s:7 title="Portuguese Subtitle"  "/root/my_dls/Output/My Vid/1/en-us/1080p/My Video - 1 [Dual Audio].mkv"
```

Comment: Share full log.